# How to hide all div's with a data-type that isn't the select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table, with cells, and each cell has a data-type.  I have a filter bar, and when a filter option is selected I want to hide all the div's with the data-type that isn't the selected option.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Not sure where to start i guess

Comment: @James show that you tried. Then more people might like to help you.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can grab all divs with a custom data-type? I don't feel like this is an unreasonable thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your selector first get all elements that have the attribute set to anything, then select those that do not match `value`

```
$('div[data-type][data-type!="value"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your divs have a "data-type" attribute, so you can do something like:

```
$('div[data-type!="yourvalue"]').hide();
```

Comment: This is helpful, however it also hides the divs without that data-type